# Adding event to native calendar in react-native iOS is not working

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add event from my react-native ios app to native calendar. But it does not show any event.

Comment: Please post your code.  It's impossible to answer your question without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else coming to this question who is using the [React Native Calendar Events module](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events), there's [an issue](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events/issues/8) where if you don't specify an end date when creating an event then it won't work. If you specify `endDate` in your call to `saveEvent`, e.g.:

`RNCalendarEvents.saveEvent('title', { location: 'location', notes: 'notes', startDate: '2016-10-01T09:45:00.000UTC', endDate: '2016-10-01T10:45:00.000UTC' }`

then an event should be created.

Comment: Throwing an error. saying unhandled promise rejection typeError  null is not an object(Evaluating CalanderEvents.saveEvent)